# How to create an if statement based on multiple conditions?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I'm trying to implement an `if` condition in Matlab that when two objects get at a distance of 30 meters of each other should accelerate until 100 m and after that it should behave normal. The condition should not work when the distance gets lower than 100 m but only when it reaches 29 m or below, until 100 m.

As I've read, Matlab will only take the first statement from the left so I was thinking to write the condition in 2 steps, but got stuck.

This is what I've done so far:

```
%%%%functia ----osc----simplu
function yprim=osccar1(t,y)
global dist1
if dist1<30
    antr=1;
elseif dist1>30
    antr=1;
end
if dist1<100
    bntr=1;
else
    bntr=2;
end
%    if dist1<30 && (dist1<100)
%         indth=1;
%    elseif dist1<100
%        indth=1;
%    else
%         indth=0;
%     end

magn=(y(1)^2+y(2)^2+y(3)^2)^(3/2);
yprim=zeros(6,1);
% if indth==1
if antr==bntr
    yprim(1,1)=y(4);
    yprim(2,1)=y(5)-0.001;
    yprim(3,1)=y(6);
    yprim(4,1)=double(y(1)/magn);
    yprim(5,1)=double(y(2)/magn);
    yprim(6,1)=double(y(3)/magn);
else
    yprim(1,1)=y(4);
    yprim(2,1)=y(5);
    yprim(3,1)=y(6);
    yprim(4,1)=double(y(1)/magn);
    yprim(5,1)=double(y(2)/magn);
    yprim(6,1)=double(y(3)/magn);
end
```

Comment: not an error message , but didn't had the behavior that I wanted. It just skipped the if condition. The solution proposed by HansHirse works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying the problem, but isn't the answer just:

```
if (dist1 < 30)
  accelerate = 1;
elseif (dist1 > 100)
  accelerate = 0;
end
```

If `dist1` is below 30, accelerate. If `dist1` is above 100, stop accelerating. If `dist1` is between 30 and 100, don't do anything. Either, we are stil accelerating from before and thus `dist1` is rising, or we don't accelerate and `dist1` is falling.

Of course, this only holds, if the state of `accelerate` is (also) persisted somewhere. If not, please provide some more context on how and where this function is used.

Also:

> As I've read , matlab will only take the first statement from the left [...]

[Logical Short-Circuiting](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html#bt_0nai-1) is a bit different.